# Getting Call value is null

Tags: java, android

In my code I am getting a value of Call is null. i.e I am using three internal API's they are Call.java

http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Call.java.html

CallManger.java

http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java.html and

Connection.java

http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Connection.java.html.

I created subclass for Call and connection class.

```
public class MyCall extends Call{   

    CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance(); 
    Phone.State state;
    Connection c;
     Phone mDefaultPhone;
     private final ArrayList<Connection> emptyConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();    


     Call ringingCall;

    @Override
    public List<Connection> getConnections() {              
        System.out.println("before if****"+ringingCall);
    if(ringingCall != null){                
        System.out.println("inside if****");
        ringingCall = (Call) cm.getForegroundCalls();
        System.out.println("**call is not null***");
        System.out.println("value of call"+ringingCall);
        return ((Call) ringingCall).getConnections();
    }           
            else
             {
                 System.out.println("**list is  null***");
                 return emptyConnections;
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public Phone getPhone() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void hangup() throws CallStateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMultiparty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public Connection
    getEarliestConnection() {
        System.out.println("inside EarliestConnection"); 
        List l;
        long time = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        Connection c;
        Connection earliest = null;

        l = getConnections();
        System.out.println("value of connection is=="+l); 
        if (l == null) {
            return null;
        }else if ( l.size() == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }


        for (int i = 0, s = l.size() ; i < s ; i++) {
            c = (Connection) l.get(i);
            long t;

            t = c.getCreateTime();

            if (t < time) {
                earliest = c;
                time = t;
            }
        }

        return earliest;
    }
  }
```

I called CallManger like this :

```
CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();
```

My another class is CallUpdate . It should give me a OutgoingCall States(i.e states of other end phone is Busy, power-off or not-reachable) .

```
public class CallUpdate {   

    Call myCall = new MyCall();
    Connection myConn = new MyConnection();
    CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();

        public Object getCallFailedString(){

           myConn = myCall.getEarliestConnection();
           System.out.println("myConn is  ******"+myConn);
           System.out.println("myCall is  ******"+myCall);  

           if(myConn == null){
                System.out.println("myConn is null ******");
                return null;
           }                
          else
            {
               Connection.DisconnectCause cause = myConn.getDisconnectCause();                       
               System.out.println("myconn is not null ******"+cause);   


                switch(cause){

                 case BUSY :
                   System.out.println("inside busy");
                 break;

                 case NUMBER_UNREACHABLE :
                    System.out.println("inside un-reachable");
                 break;

                case POWER_OFF :
                   System.out.println("inside power off");
                 break;  
              }     


        }
    return myConn;
 }

}
```

But I am getting Call value is null in the above method of Call.java.

Call ringingCall

```
    public List<Connection> getConnections() {              
     System.out.println("before if****"+ringingCall);
    if(ringingCall != null){                
    System.out.println("inside if****");
    ringingCall = (Call) cm.getForegroundCalls();
    System.out.println("**call is not null***");
    System.out.println("value of call"+ringingCall);
    return ((Call) ringingCall).getConnections();
}           
        else
         {
             System.out.println("**list is  null***");
             return emptyConnections;
    }   
    }
```

The rigingCall values is null. Why this value is null? Is I am doing in correct way ?. plz help me

Thx in advance.

Comment: @Vanathi: Can u answer my Question? Is I am going correct way?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Android. But you can try `Call ringingCall = new Call();` instead of `Call ringingCall = null;` as Brian answered.

Comment: @shiv1229 - reading over all the questions you've asked about this, it would appear you're engaging in form of cargo cult programming. Without understanding what it is you're typing in, being able to produce working code is going to be random luck, at best. I would suggest a good beginner's book on Java, or the Oracle java tutorials at the very least.

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize `ringingCall` in your `MyCall` class, therefore it is `null`.

This leads to `myConn` also being `null` looking through your code.

Comment: Call ringingCall = null; Iinitialized like this in MyCall class but still the ringingCall is null

Comment: @Brain: R u there? plz tell me how to initialize.

Comment: you cannot initialize this class on your own. because call related operations run in different android application therefor in different dvm. Also when the phone ringing occurs phone class initializes by the android os containing all info, all you need is to fetch that class object, but unfortunately you cant.